# A possible infinite recompile was detected for SQLHANDLE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, execution-plan, errors, plan-cache

I have been finding strange error messages on the sql error log:

Bocss: same deadlock taking place every hour – needs investigating

Also lots of recompiles are listed in the error log for other SPIDs as per following examples:

> 09/04/2015 14:30:10,spid64,Unknown,A possible infinite recompile was
>   detected for SQLHANDLE
>   0x0200000059631A288882589E0C54B76404CAE1B97E08D3680000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   PlanHandle
>   0x0600040059631A2860A62B654100000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   starting offset 1038 ending offset 2600.  The last recompile
>   reason was 2. 09/04/2015 14:30:10,spid150,Unknown,A possible infinite
>   recompile was detected for SQLHANDLE
>   0x02000000EF886F018C4E0B163812B8B20150FE8FC7E6A06A0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   PlanHandle
>   0x06000400EF886F01901A816E0600000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   starting offset 998 ending offset 2520.  The last recompile reason
>   was 2. 09/04/2015 14:30:09,spid67,Unknown,A possible infinite
>   recompile was detected for SQLHANDLE
>   0x0200000057C4C632D9052275CFF2B683B80F29501EE91D730000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   PlanHandle
>   0x0600040057C4C63200EAC2BE3000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   starting offset 1064 ending offset 2652.  The last recompile
>   reason was 2. 09/04/2015 14:30:09,spid163,Unknown,A possible infinite
>   recompile was detected for SQLHANDLE
>   0x02000000E7C7BF0E5D70DE55759C7842860272AD474D69AB0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   PlanHandle
>   0x06000400E7C7BF0EF0EB68A52C00000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   starting offset 1028 ending offset 2580.  The last recompile
>   reason was 2.

what could have caused this?

Looks like I don't have the plans in cache anymore.
[image]

following the advice of this post 
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1479420-146-1.aspx

> then as a safety measure disabled the full text catalogs, this made
>   no difference, so then I fully rolled back the changes (dropped the
>   new objects etc). This also made no difference, in the end the only
>   thing that seemed to stop it was a restart of the SQL instances, this
>   immediately resolved the issue.

this sorted me out as well, however, I am still to find what caused this mess at the first place?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [Infinite recompile message in the errorlog](http://web.archive.org/web/20160222013613/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/04/21/580896.aspx) on the SQL Programmability & API Development Team Blog, this message is triggered when a statement in a batch recompiles 100 times in a row.

This message does not necessarily mean there is a problem; it exists to help troubleshoot statements that might legitimately be recompiling that often (for example, due to rapid changes in statistics), as well as real infinite compilation loops (which would be rare in the extreme).

You should start by identifying the triggering statement from the information provided, and evaluate it in the context of the numeric code giving the reason for the recompilations. There is a table of these codes and their meanings in several places in Books Online, including under the [SP:Recompile Event Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187105.aspx).

There is more information available in [Plan Caching and Recompilation in SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn148262.aspx).

[image: Table of values]

Answer (score 2):

I also could not find the plan until I come across [this script](https://sqlsoldier.net/wp/sqlserver/possibleinfiniterecompilewasdetectedforsqlhandle), which finds the exact sql statement which originated that warning:

```
Declare @ErrorLog Table (LogID int identity(1, 1) not null primary key,
        LogDate datetime null, 
        ProcessInfo nvarchar(100) null,
        LogText nvarchar(4000) null);

Insert Into @ErrorLog (LogDate, ProcessInfo, LogText)
Exec master..xp_readerrorlog;

With Recompiles
As (Select LogID, LogDate,
        SPID = Replace(ProcessInfo, 'spid', ''),
        SQLHandle = Convert(varbinary(64),
                SUBSTRING(LogText, CHARINDEX('SQLHANDLE', LogText) + 10,
                    CharIndex(',', LogText) - CHARINDEX('SQLHANDLE', LogText) - 10), 1),
        PlanHandle = Convert(varbinary(64),
                SUBSTRING(LogText, CHARINDEX('PLANHANDLE', LogText) + 11,
                    CharIndex(',', LogText, CHARINDEX('PLANHANDLE', LogText)) -
                    CHARINDEX('PLANHANDLE', LogText) - 11), 1),
        StartingOffset = Convert(int,
                SUBSTRING(LogText, CHARINDEX('starting offset', LogText) + 16,
                    CharIndex(',', LogText, CHARINDEX('starting offset', LogText)) -
                    CHARINDEX('starting offset', LogText) - 16)),
        EndingOffset = Convert(int,
                SUBSTRING(LogText, CHARINDEX('ending offset', LogText) + 14,
                    CharIndex('.', LogText, CHARINDEX('ending offset', LogText)) -
                    CHARINDEX('ending offset', LogText) - 14)),
        LastRecompileReason = SUBSTRING(LogText, CHARINDEX('last recompile reason was', LogText) + 26,
                CharIndex('.', LogText, CHARINDEX('last recompile reason was', LogText)) -
                CHARINDEX('last recompile reason was', LogText) - 26)
    From @ErrorLog
    Where CharIndex('A possible infinite recompile was detected for SQLHANDLE', LogText) > 0)
Select R.SPID, R.LogDate,
    LastRecompileReason = Case R.LastRecompileReason When 1 Then 'Schema changed'
            When 2 Then 'Statistics changed (' + R.LastRecompileReason + ')'
            When 3 Then 'Deferred compile (' + R.LastRecompileReason + ')'
            When 4 Then 'Set option changed (' + R.LastRecompileReason + ')'
            When 5 Then 'Temp table changed (' + R.LastRecompileReason + ')'
            When 6 Then 'Remote rowset changed (' + R.LastRecompileReason + ')'
            When 7 Then 'For Browse permissions changed (' + R.LastRecompileReason + ')'
            When 8 Then 'Query notification environment changed (' + R.LastRecompileReason + ')'
            When 9 Then 'Partition view changed (' + R.LastRecompileReason + ')'
            When 10 Then 'Cursor options changed (' + R.LastRecompileReason + ')'
            When 11 Then 'Option (recompile) requested (' + R.LastRecompileReason + ')'
            Else 'Unknown (' + R.LastRecompileReason + ')'
        End,
    DBName = DB_NAME(ST.dbid),
    ObjectName = IsNull(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(ST.objectid, ST.dbid) + N'.', '') +
        IsNull(OBJECT_NAME(ST.objectid, ST.dbid), N'ad hoc or prepared'),
    Command = SUBSTRING(ST.TEXT,
            R.StartingOffset / 2 + 1,
            ((Case R.EndingOffset When -1 THEN DATALENGTH(ST.text)
                Else R.EndingOffset
            End) - R.StartingOffset) / 2 + 1),
    QueryPlan = QP.query_plan,
    FullSQLText = ST.text
From Recompiles As R
Outer Apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(R.SQLHandle) As ST
Outer Apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(R.PlanHandle) As QP
Order By R.LogID Desc;
```